# how to get UDP traffic via PHP and show it in a web page?

Tags: php, html, sockets

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

I have a service that continuously sends data (binary images) to 127.255.255.255 in order to permit every future local service to get that data if needed.

is it possible to get that UDP data traffic via php in order to show it to the user whenever he/she is going to connect to the web server installed on the pc?

I already tried to create a socket in php and get data (simple data just to prove communication) and it works if I run the php code via command line, but if I visit the web page via browser I cannot see anything and I can see the web page that continuously load data until the moment it stops and show the data.
This means that the php page can get data but it is going to show it only when the application stops.

I would like that when I visit that web page, I could see data streaming and only when I change web page the application stops.

The application seems to run for 30 seconds and memorize all the output and after that will write the output on the screen. 30 seconds are not setted by me, the app should run forever because it is into while(true) loop.

this is the code:

```
<body style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="margin: auto; margin-top: 50px;">
            <div style="margin: auto; width: 200px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; color: darkgreen;">Real Time View</div>

            <?php
                //Create a UDP socket
                if(!($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)))
                {
                     $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                     $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

                     die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
                }

                //echo "Socket created <br>";

                if( !socket_set_nonblock($socket) ){
                     $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                     $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

                     die("Could not nonblock socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
                }   

                // Bind the source address
                if( !socket_bind($socket, "0.0.0.0" , 9999) ){
                     $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                     $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

                     die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
                }   
                //echo "Socket bind OK <br>";

                while(1){
                     //echo "Waiting for data ... <br>";

                     //Receive some data
                     //$r = socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
                     //echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf ."<br>";

                     $r = socket_read($socket, 1024);
                     echo $r; 

                     //Send back the data to the client
                     //socket_sendto($socket, "OK " . $buf , 100 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
                }
                socket_close($socket);


            ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the [flush() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

"Flushes the write buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc). This attempts to push current output all the way to the browser with a few caveats."

You probably also have to call `ob_flush;`
So if you put the following on strategic places it should work:

```
echo "something";
flush();
ob_flush();
```

You can let PHP run infinite with `set_time_limit(0)`.
See the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).
So put this line on top of your php file.

Also check out the `default_socket_timeout` setting if you have problems after 60 seconds.

**Edit**: Running the script here now for 30 minutes without a problem. Even httpd cpu is low now. (due to the usleep i think)

My working code:

```
<?
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  set_time_limit(0);
  ob_start();

  function flush_buffers(){
      ob_end_flush();
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      ob_start();
  }
  echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s");

?>
<body style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="margin: auto; margin-top: 50px;">
            <div style="margin: auto; width: 200px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; color: darkgreen;">Real Time View</div>

            <?php
                //Create a UDP socket
                if(!($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)))
                {
                     $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                     $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
                     die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
                }

                echo "Socket created <br>";
                flush_buffers();

                if( !socket_set_nonblock($socket) ){
                     $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                     $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
                     die("Could not nonblock socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
                }

                // Bind the source address
                if( !socket_bind($socket, "0.0.0.0" , 9999) ){
                     $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                     $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
                     die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
                }
                echo "Socket bind OK <br>";
                flush_buffers();

                socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>1, "usec"=>100));
                socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array("sec"=>1, "usec"=>100));

                try {
                  while(1){
                       usleep(0.5 * 1000000); // 0.5 seconds
                       if (False === ($r = socket_read($socket, 1024))) {
                          $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                          $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
                          if ($errorcode!='11') { echo "error reading : [$errorcode] $errormsg <br>\n"; }
                       }
                       echo $r;
                       if ($r!='') { echo ".<br>"; }
                       flush_buffers();
                  }
                } finally {
                  socket_close($socket);
                }


            ?>
    </div>
</body>
<?
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. flush doesn't work. It seems that using it nothing changes. It seems that the application memorize all the output and when it stops running the output will be written. Another problem is that the application stops to run after 30 seconds without any reason

Comment: The default for limit on running php script is 30 seconds. You can change that with set_time_limit (int $seconds). I'll take a look at your source.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's broader question?

Comment: @GlenH7: What broader question? His original question was different. He had a problem whith flushing output before the PHP script was ready.

Comment: Yes, the OP could have done a better job at being more clear. It's in the title and the 5th paragraph. `I would like that when I visit that web page, I could see data streaming and only when I change web page the application stops.`

Comment: He could use set_time_limit(0) but i don't know (yet) if its recomended. But i think his flush isn't working yet. I'll have to check the source.

Comment: Edited my answer to include `ob_flush();` besides `flush();`. In combination with the `set_time_limit(0);` it should all work. Although there is also a `default_socket_timeout` setting in my php.ini which you should check out.

Comment: @Rik I have placed `ob_start()` at the top of the code, `ob_end_flush()` at the end of it and after I have added into the loop `echo $r; flush(); ob_flush();`. Furthermore, I have added `set_time_limit(0)` at the top of the code and have changed the default_socket_timeout to 0 (before was setted to 60). Now it is running forever but I still can't get the output while the app is running

Comment: @Rik when you tried the app could you get the output prompted in the web page while the app was running?

Comment: Yep. Output came while the page was 'loading'. I kept the busy-mouse while on the page my messages appeared. Could you try my working code (in the answer).

Comment: @Rik I tried your code and like mine I get no output while the app is running. I get the output only when the app stops after few minutes. I write wrong in the question, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and not wheezy (other pc). Could be caused by the browser? I'm using firefox

Comment: I used Chrome. Second time i tried it keeps messing up my httpd-process. Now i also don't receive anything but my httpd is at 97%. You should probably build in some process-managing (sleep of socket_read_if_data).

Comment: I have understood that the application stops because it crashes. I know that thanks an `echo` after the `while` (also with `flush_buffers`) and no output was prompted, so it crashes into the `while`. Anyway, do you have any other alternatives to do what I would like to do? java applet?

Comment: it crashes after 4 minutes more or less

Comment: You could try  a new middle part i inserted (from the `while ($r` to the `flush`. If you can see the -.- coming on each line the flushing works. It works here in Chrome and IE. (but doesn't receive data anymore ;<). Perhaps is a client side receive in the browser with javascript a better solution. Then you don't put any strain on the server. And if the user is offline with the browser the php also doesn't run. (I haven't checked for sources with javascript and udp)

Comment: Changed the code again. It works here again (Chrome and IE). Now my httpd keeps a low profile. Although i need to restart httpd because after i stop the page my `netstat -an | grep 9999` still shows a listening process. But perhaps you can reuse the socket with SO_REUSEADDR. I also read that javascript could not do udp. Perhaps java could but that outside my area.

Comment: now it works but it takes very long time before showing the output. Anyway, thank you very much!!! I will work starting from here. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned by the answers, the PHP script has a limited of execution time. In the default case this will be 30 seconds. In your script, there is a while loop to read the socket data. However, this makes the script runs infinity that is not expected by the server. The browser read the data in until the script is killed by the server.

You do need to this differently. The browser is not expecting a live stream in this case. You could do this with PHP and send the correct headers to the browser: stream/mjpg? for example. Than it should be able to show the image stream. Another possibility is to use javascript sockets to read the data and outputs it to the browser elements.